# How can I verify little snitch warnings on SSH processes?

Tags: macos, security, ssh, signature

It's been a while since I've needed to connect to a server via SSH. When I tried to connect today, Little Snitch gave me this warning:

> The program "ssh" has been modified
>
> Previously, the program had the identifier "com.apple.openssh", but
> now it's "com.apple.ssh". This probably means that Apple decided to
> rename the process. But please inspect the names! If a process has
> been replaced with a script interpreter such as Python, its rules may
> be hijacked by a script virus.

[image: Apple SSH warning]

And this is probably nothing, but looking at the binary in a code editor, I noticed the first 8 characters say "cafe babe". Strange, right?

[image: Apple SSH binary 'cafe babe']

I couldn't find any info about it online, so I installed openssh via Homebrew. But when I run that, Little Snitch warns that the process has no signature.

[image: Homebrew SSH unsigned warning]

Anyway, I checked the signature on the Apple binary using `codesign -db --verbose=4 /usr/bin/ssh`, but I can't find anything online to compare the output against.

**So how can I be sure this binary is legit before allowing it to connect?**

BTW, I'm running Ventura 13.1.

Edit: Here's the output of `codesign -dv --verbose=4 /usr/bin/ssh`:

```
Executable=/usr/bin/ssh
Identifier=com.apple.ssh
Format=Mach-O universal (x86_64 arm64e)
CodeDirectory v=20400 size=6182 flags=0x0(none) hashes=183+7 location=embedded
Platform identifier=14
VersionPlatform=1
VersionMin=852224
VersionSDK=852224
Hash type=sha256 size=32
CandidateCDHash sha256=d19d6f7a19eb7178c68fc67c197bc8d8fbeda7e7
CandidateCDHashFull sha256=d19d6f7a19eb7178c68fc67c197bc8d8fbeda7e791bd5a9e96f67e9b2169eb16
Hash choices=sha256
CMSDigest=d19d6f7a19eb7178c68fc67c197bc8d8fbeda7e791bd5a9e96f67e9b2169eb16
CMSDigestType=2
Executable Segment base=0
Executable Segment limit=671744
Executable Segment flags=0x1
Page size=4096
Launch Constraints:
    None
CDHash=d19d6f7a19eb7178c68fc67c197bc8d8fbeda7e7
Signature size=4442
Authority=Software Signing
Authority=Apple Code Signing Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Signed Time=Nov 5, 2022 at 12:44:29 AM
Info.plist=not bound
TeamIdentifier=not set
Sealed Resources=none
Internal requirements count=1 size=64
```

Output of 'uname -a':

```
Darwin MacBook-Pro.local 22.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 22.2.0: Fri Nov 11 02:08:47 PST 2022; root:xnu-8792.61.2~4/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Comment: cafebabe is the Java & Mach-O magic number, so that alone is no indicator.

Comment: `xxd /usr/bin/ssh|head` also shows`cafe babe` in my Big Sur machine.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Can you run `/sbin/md5 /usr/bin/ssh` and see whether you get 28dae2824341539a9e4d073b28bc0b89 ?

Comment: @nohillside Yes, I get that same hash.

Comment: Good, so it's the same binary after all. The hashes returned by codesign aren't the identical globally then.

Comment: @nohillside Awesome. Then I'll go ahead and let it run.  Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you indeed are running `/usr/bin/ssh` and didn't play around with SIP or SSV then you can assume that the binary is legit.

SSV (Sealed System Volume) ensures that your macOS install can't be tampered with (the system simply refuses to boot if somebody tries).

PS: For Ventura 13.1 I get the following hash for `ssh`:

```
$ uname -a
Darwin Sumtri.local 22.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 22.2.0: Fri Nov 11 02:04:44 PST 2022; root:xnu-8792.61.2~4/RELEASE_ARM64_T8103 arm64
$ /sbin/md5 /usr/bin/ssh
MD5 (/usr/bin/ssh) = 28dae2824341539a9e4d073b28bc0b89
```